# janrain certificate and hostname missmatch

Tags: certificate, hostname, janrain

i'm trying to use Janrain on a cordova/crosswalk application.
This works fine while i stay on the same domain.
yet when i try to switch domaing ( development, staging, live) i get a certificate error: hostname does not match. "dev does not match live", "dev does not match stag".

I have enlisted all my domains to the whitelist (client and server side) yet this error keeps occuring.
I also noticed that once in a week i can use a different domain, witch results in "live does not match dev", "live does not match stag".

Is this a caching problem where the host name is stored and cleared on a weekly basis ?

Comment: If you have log files of the actual API calls or endpoints your app is using that would be useful for troubleshooting.

Also, its important to clarify what Janrain Product you are trying to use "Social Login(Engage)" or "Registration(Capture)".

In general Janrain doesn't do caching of domains, it seems like you may just be having some configuration issues.